# Cannot render an image using Razor View

Tags: c#, razor

Problem:
Even though the image path is correct, the image cannot be rendered on a browser using Razor View. Also, the image is not corrupted because a HTML file can reference to the image properly.

Code:

*Index.cshtml*

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    var workingDirectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    var projectDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
    var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(workingDirectory, "wwwroot", "images", "sampleImage.png");
}

<div class="text-center">
    <p>@System.IO.File.Exists(path)</p> // returns True

    <img src="@path" alt="error" />
</div>
```

That would be really nice if anyone could help this problem!!

Answer (score 1):

File.Exists is run on the server. src is requested from the client. Try

```
src = "@Url.Content("~/images/sampleImage.png")"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

In my project, @Url.Content(path); works fine, but "Html" doesn't have Content method. Also, just src="~/images/sampleImage.png" works properly.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!